motor and holybro tekko esc heating issue
I recently started building a quadcopter. I'm using a Hollybro Tekko 4-in-one ESC and Emax motors (EMAX RS2205 2300KV Brushless DC Motor for FPV Racing Drone) - Red Cap (CCW Motor Rotation) X4).
In flight test I observed heating happening in both motors and the ESC. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this issue, and how to fix it?
